# Storing configuration variable in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm storing configuration variables for different environments in the production.rb and development.rb

> production.rb
>
> ENV['my_variable'] = 'val1'
>
> development.rb
>
> ENV['my_variable'] = 'val2'

Maybe exists another way to store variables for different environments. What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been pointing people towards the `settings`gem lately. [Settings Gem](http://github.com/citrusbyte/settings)